# Module loads in dev but not in production (Rails / Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

The module I'm trying to load, works in development, but not in production:

```
# /app/controllers/concerns/response.rb
module Response
  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end
end
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Response
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end
```

I can use the json_response no problem in development, but not in production. When sending to heroku I get this error:

```
/app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Response (NameError)
```

The module exists in /app/ so it should be autoloaded. What am I missing?

Comment: please check the branch you have deployed has this module.

Comment: If after trying what Sachin suggested and that doesn't work, then I believe `config.dependency_loading` might be turned off for the production environment. Please check that this is turned on in `config/environments/production.rb`. Or, add this line `config.dependency_loading = true` at the bottom of your `config/environments/production.rb` file

Comment: Using heroku bash I can verify the file exists. And dependency_loading config is turned on now with no affect. This is my first time doing a Rails API only app - anything around that I could be missing? @NwochaAdim

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

```
bundle exec rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
```

It should show autoload_paths includes `app/controllers/concerns`. If it doesn't, add it to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns)
```

If it not work, the other way is try to wrap your `concern` in Concerns module:

```
module Concerns
  module Response
    def json_response(object, status = :ok)
      render json: object, status: status
    end
  end
end
```

And in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Concerns::Response
end
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe your issue caused by autoload path is disable in production by default (https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html). So please try to add it in eager_load_path:

```
# In application.rb
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns)
```

Comment: Tried with no luck. This was my first thought too - but it still seems to not work in production/staging (heroku) and still doing just fine locally.

Comment: Still no luck in production (fine locally) now error is "uninitialized constant Concerns::Response"

Comment: What is `bundle exec rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` show on production?

Comment: It gives me the same error and doesn't print out any paths. This has to be some naming issue right? Should I just copy and paste my methods into application_controller.rb?

Comment: I have added the reason may cause your issue. One more try.

Comment: I appreciate the help. The problem still persists.

Comment: Anyway, I think require explicitly module is also a way you can try: 

(in application_controller.rb)
`require_relative 'concerns/response'`

. If it still not work, you have to `json_response` to `ApplicationController`.